# How I can generalise this code

Tags: r

I have this code and I want to generalize it and make it efficient. Each time I generate a number of random variables and I put it in the m equation to generate m. Can I get any help to simplify this code till `m[20]` ?

```
m[0]=0
x=rnorm(1,0,1)
m[1]=max(0,x[1]-0.2+m[0])
x=rnorm(2,0,1)
m[2]=max(0,x[2]-0.2+max(0,x[1]-0.2+m[0]))
x=rnorm(3,0,1)
m[3]=max(0,x[3]-0.2+max(0,x[2]-0.2+max(0,x[1]-0.2+m[0])))
```

and continue till I get to `m[20]`

Comment: Your title is very generic and I'm not sure if your code is really complete or not, or what it's suppose to do. It seems you're missing one or two `)` at the end.

Comment: it appears OP wants to DRY up his code. Please add an explanation of what the code is meant to do and I can look into it - I have a colleague who uses R so this would be a good learning exercise for him :-)

Answer (score 3):

Judging by this:

> ```
> x=rnorm(2,0,1)
> m[2]=max(0,x[2]-0.2+max(0,x[1]-0.2+m[0]))
> x=rnorm(3,0,1)
> m[3]=max(0,x[3]-0.2+max(0,x[2]-0.2+max(0,x[1]-0.2+m[0])))
> ```

It looks like we can generalize the logic of setting `m` like this:

$$
m[n] = \max(0, x[n] - 0.2 + m[n-1])
$$

So you need some kind of recursive function. Maybe something like this:

```
calc.m <- function(n, x=NULL, accum=c()) {
  if (n == 0) c()
  else {
    if (is.null(x)) x = rnorm(n, 0, 1)
    mz <- calc.m(n - 1, x, accum)
    c(mz, max(0, x[n] - 0.2 + mz[length(mz)]))
  }
}
```

This is not exactly what your sample is doing above. But I hope it comes close enough. This is just to get you started.